# hornetq message remain in queue after ack

Tags: hornetq

We are using hornetq-core 2.2.21.Final stand-alone after reading a non-transnational message , the message still remains in queue although it acknowledge 
session is created using

```
sessionFactory.createSession(true, true, 0)
```

locator setting:

```
val transConf = new TransportConfiguration(classOf[NettyConnectorFactory].getName,map)
val locator = HornetQClient.createServerLocatorWithoutHA(transConf) 
locator.setBlockOnDurableSend(false)
locator.setBlockOnNonDurableSend(false)
locator.setAckBatchSize(0) // also tried without this setting
locator.setConsumerWindowSize(0)// also tried without this setting
```

Message is acknowledge using message.acknowledge ()

I think that the problem might be two queues on the same address 
also tried to set the message expiration but it didn't help , messages are still piling up in the queue
please advise

Comment: You should add how you are acknoledging. Most likely you missed something on the code. Please re-edit your question with this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using the core api. Are you explicitly calling acknowledge on the messages?

If you have two queues on the same address ack will only ack the messages on the queue you are consuming. On that case the system is acting normally.

Comment: yes , I have put some more info in my question 
Message is acknowledge using message.acknowledge ()
I think that the problem might be two queues on the same address

Comment: Why don't you just put some complete code on the way you're doing.. I can't just guess to give you an answer

Comment: It's a big system and the code is embedded with several readers , but anyway I found the problem , and it was due to different queues on the same address so actually the message was acknowledge on a different queue with the same address. BTW , is the a good monitoring tool that can help us see , queues / messages /how many messages in each queue / view them